# Generic type constraint not applying

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I'm writing an emulator and I came across an interesting error:

> error CS0311: The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method `'Emulator.Emulator<T>'`. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'T' to `'Emulator.Emulator<T>.EmulatorState'`.

The error is on the following code (specifically the T at Emulator.IOpcode):

```
protected abstract class Chip8Opcode<T> : Emulator<T>.IOpcode where T : Chip8.Chip8State
```

The simplified code is below ([ideone](http://ideone.com/or1H49)):

```
public abstract class Emulator<T> where T : Emulator<T>.EmulatorState
{
    public abstract class EmulatorState { }
    public interface IOpcode
    {
        bool IsValid(T state);
        void Execute(T state);
    }
}

public class Chip8 : Emulator<Chip8.Chip8State>
{
    public class Chip8State : EmulatorState { }
}

abstract class Chip8Opcode<T> : Emulator<T>.IOpcode where T : Chip8.Chip8State
{
}
```

To my understanding the T should be limited to Chip8State, which can be converted to EmulatorState (which is what Emulator<> requires), however it seems that the generic type constraint isn't applying to the `T` in `Emulator<T>`, as the error is "The type 'T'" and not "The type 'Chip8State'."  Is this a bug in the compilation or is there a better way to apply type constraints to inherited generics?

Note: This is not a duplicate to similar questions about type collisions, since T is never seen as the constrained type.

Also: Generics are in place to allow easy extending of the emulator if needed later, although it would be nice to know if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: "Is this a bug in the compilation?" -- certainly not in this case, and frankly one should pretty much assume that is _never_ the case, even though extremely rarely it is. Anyway, I don't know what it is you want instead here, but the error here is pretty clear: `T` does not inherit the type nested inside `Emulator<T>` as the constraint requires; instead, it inherits the type nested inside `Chip8`. The type `Emulator<T>.EmulatorState` is a _completely different_ type from `Chip8.EmulatorState`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Chip8.EmulatorState is not defined, Chip8.Chip8State extends EmulatorState, which is what the generic constraint on T in Emulator requires.  Even if it was separate, the compiler is still not applying the constraints to T, as shown in the error

Comment: Yes, I understand. I just mistyped the type name. Replace `Chip8.EmulatorState` with `Chip8.Chip8State` in my comment (the comment is too old for me to edit)

Comment: I still don't follow, `Chip8State` extends `EmulatorState`, so they're not completely different; since any method or variable from `EmulatorState` will exist in `Chip8State`, therefore they're directly related.

Comment: Sorry...I'm having trouble expressing myself. You are correct the types are related...you can assign `Chip8.Chip8State` to `Emulator<Chip8.Chip8State>.EmulatorState`. But that doesn't satisfy the generic constraint. I will try to think if I can come up with a good way to actually describe this. Or I will just wait for Jon Skeet to see your question, because he's way better at communicating this sort of thing than I am. :)

Comment: What you're trying to get is covariance in class generics, which is not possible in C#. You can only declare interfaces to be invariant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just put it like:

```
abstract class Chip8Opcode<T> : Emulator<Chip8.Chip8State>.IOpcode
    where T : Chip8.Chip8State
```

Also, check that subject about "covariance and contravariance in generics". It is only possible with interfaces in C#, to some extent.

Comment: While I'm not 100% sure it will work later on, I can't think of any counterexamples.  You are correct that it's lack of covariance in generics, I can't think of reasons why it wouldn't be included, but maybe they'll add it later

Comment: @Qwerty01: a restriction due to variance issues is in my experience always valid; i.e. one can come up with a counter-example where if the inheritance were allowed, the compiler would allow some compile-time code that would be invalid at run-time (i.e. assigning the wrong type of object reference to some other). Based on your example, I think Leandro's recommendation should work fine; but note that you could also express the type relationships as interfaces, which are then implemented by specific types. As interfaces, you can use `in` and `out` on type parameters to allow variance.

Comment: @Qwerty01: note that I'm not saying I have a counter-example off the top of my head. But I would bet good money one could come up with one in this case.

Comment: @PeterDuniho yea :/
@LeandroTaset the only issue with the code is `IOpcode` contains a function that uses `T` as the argument type, so using `Chip8.Chip8State` as the generic for `Emulator` doesn't allow any children to use their own `Chip8State` implementation without explicit casting, which is what I was trying to implement, I'll have to see if I can do it via interfaces or just force explicit casting

Comment: @Qwerty01: Hmm... OK. Well, I just saw the empty `IOpcode` interface and went for it. Any chance you update the question to provide the full `IOpcode` declaration? I think then perhaps it would be advisable to move this interface outside the `Emulator<T>` class and provide it with its own generic parameter.

Comment: @LeandroTaset Done.  I got it to work correctly by making an interface for `EmulatorState` and `Emulator`, which allowed me to use correct covariance and contravariance

Comment: Excellent! Glad you sorted it out.

Comment: @Qwerty01: I think it would be really helpful if you would add an answer to this question showing your interface-based solution. I see you added a brief answer, but the details would be what would make this question useful to others.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to solve the issue that I used was to create an interface for each class and have them implement it, which allowed covariance and contravariance to be applied correctly in later classes.

```
interface IEmulator<out T> where T : IEmulatorState
{ ... }
public interface IEmulatorState
{ ... }
```

which allows:

```
public abstract class Emulator<T> : IEmulator<T> where T : IEmulatorState
{ ... }

public interface IOpcode<in T> where T : IEmulatorState
{ ... }
```

and most importantly

```
abstract partial class Chip8Opcode<T> : IOpcode<T> where T : Chip8<T>.Chip8State
{ ... }
```

Comment: And note that this provides the template for finding the counter-example that shows why the declaration isn't legal without the variant interfaces. I.e. without `out` and `in` here, the compiler isn't able to (given the C# specification) validate that you won't try to return the wrong kind of `T` from the `IOpcode<T>` interface, and/or won't try to pass the wrong kind of `T` to a method in the `Emulator<T>` class. Declaring the variance explicitly gives the compiler the information it needs to let the types work together.

Comment: I would've thought there would be a way to do that in classes, but I guess there is a reason you can't

Comment: Well, the main reason you can't is that it's simply not supported in C#. The variance features are new, and apply only to interfaces and delegates (which are essentially one-method interfaces). I'll bet somewhere, Eric Lippert's written a good article explaining why it was impractical or undesirable to allow variance declarations on generic classes.